# Convert formulas to values if condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

I want to convert formulas to values in col P (ReportedGrossActivityReduction), for rows where col W (test) is Yes.

I created the following macro by recording and amended after searching online.

```
Sub q()
    Dim a As Range
    Dim b As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Set a = Range("W2").Value
    Set b = Range("P2").Value

    With ActiveSheet
        For Each b In .Range("P2")
            If a.Range("W2").Value = "Yes" Then
                Selection.Copy
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                  :=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
        Next
    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: You just want to convert formulas to values in `col P`, for rows where `col W` is `Yes`? Where is the `Selection`? (you shouldn't work off of `Selection` - is slow and brittle)

Comment: Yes, I want to convert formulas to values in col P, for rows where col W is Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (comments in code):

```
'hugely recommended to use this option
Option Explicit
'sub/macro which copies data over columns
Sub CopyYesInW()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    'determine last row in column W
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        'if Yes in W then copy from P to W in current row
        If Cells(i, "W").Value = "Yes" Then
            Cells(i, "W").Value = Cells(i, "P").Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify the cell range as the macro with the for loop is taking a significant amount of time to run? I have have around 6000 rows in the sheet where the macro is running

Comment: @theredindian Yes, place for it is in part `For i = 1 To lastRow`, here you can specify what rows you want to loop through, for example `For i = 3 to 11` will loop from 3rd row through 11th.

Comment: I have made the changes suggested, however the macro is still taking over an hour to complete as the excel file is quite large and using a lot of resources. Is there an alternative method to the "for loop"?

Comment: @theredindian Try setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the beginning and set it to `True` at the end of a macro. And loop is atomic/basic concept, there's no replacement.

Answer (score 1):

here is a "no-loop" solution to leave formula result only in column P cells whose corresponding column W cells content is "Yes":

```
Sub Main()
    Dim vals As Variant 'declare a Variant where to store an array
    With Range("W2", Cells(Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp)) ' reference column W range from row 2 down to last not empty one
        vals = .Value ' store referenced range values
        .Replace what:="Yes", replacement:=1, lookat:=xlWhole ' replace referenced range "Yes" content with a numeric one (1) to exploit subsequent SpecialCells method usage
        With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Offset(, -7) 'reference column P cells corresponding to referenced range cells with numeric content 
            .Value = .Value ' leave formula result only 
        End With
        .Value = vals ' write back original referenced range values
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @theredindian, any feedback?

Comment: this is generating a runtime error 1004 no cells were found

Comment: then there was no cell in column "W" with content "Yes"

Comment: I am not sure why it was not finding the cells with in column "W" with content "Yes", but thank you for helping me as well

Comment: You are welcome. While I'm sure why why it was not finding "Yes"